# Maximum allowed value for <input type="text"/>

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input field:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

How can I allow entering only a number that is not greater than some predefined value, like for example 10, so every attempt to enter a number greater than 10 won't be allowed?

Comment: There is nothing built-in for `text` as its purpose is text. There is for `type="number"` though.

Comment: You can control and change  html elements' values and notify people with Javascript. search for validations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript

```
function createValidator(element) {
    return function() {
        var min = parseInt(element.getAttribute("min")) || 0;
        var max = parseInt(element.getAttribute("max")) || 0;

        var value = parseInt(element.value) || min;
        element.value = value; // make sure we got an int

        if (value < min) element.value = min;
        if (value > max) element.value = max;
    }
}

var elm = document.body.querySelector("input[type=number]");
elm.onkeyup = createValidator(elm);
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10"></input>
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it should work.

Comment: i think OP wants the input as 'text' type. but yes this works if user does not type the number manually.

Comment: @drTerminal HTML5 has a number input type, so I figured it was more appropriate. Still, it's only a small change.

Comment: Tried this one as well, but nothing's happening, am I missing someting? I put the javascript within <script type="text/javascript"></script> and I put <input type="number" min="0" max="10"></input> but nothing, I still can enter a number greater than 10.

Comment: @NikolaNastevski make sure the script fires after the HTML element is parsed (i.e. put the `<script>` element _after_ the `<input>` element.

Comment: @Bart: my bad, didn't pay attention to that one, sorry :) Seems to work, thanks ;) Any chance that can validate if it's a number or not, so if it's not a number, not to allow it to be entered?

Comment: @NikolaNastevski updated my post - input is now always a number and defaults to "min"

Comment: @Bart: I think we have a winner :) Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Convert the value to a number immediately, then compare it to a maximum value:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("text1");
    var maxVal = 10;

    addEvent(textbox, "keyup", function () {
        var thisVal = +this.value;

        this.className = this.className.replace(" input-error ", "");
        if (isNaN(thisVal) || thisVal > maxVal) {
            this.className += " input-error ";
            // Invalid input
        }
    });
};

function addEvent(element, event, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + event, callback);
    } else {
        element["on" + event] = callback;
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jBFHn/

As you type, if the value isn't a number or the value is greater than the maximum, the "input-error" `class` is added to the element. You can take out the whole `class` changing, and put in your own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used this property in my project.

```
<script>
function integerInRange(value, min, max, name) {

    if(value < min || value > max)
    {
        document.getElementById(name).value = "100";
        alert("Write here your message");
    }
}
</script>
```

And my input like this

```
<input type="text" id="yyy" name="xxx" onkeyup="integerInRange(this.value, 0, 100, "yyy")" />
```

If you using bootstrap you can use alert window!
    
    function integerInRange(value, min, max, name) {

```
    if(value < min || value > max)
    {
        document.getElementById(name).value = "100";
        $.pnotify({ title: 'UYARI', text: 'Girilen değer ' + min + ' ile ' + max + ' arasında olmalıdır.', type: 'error' });
        $(".ui-pnotify-history-container").remove();
    }
}
```