# Setting a maximum value less than a number on a decimal based input field

Tags: html, forms, validation, html-input

I'm making an input field that accepts any number of decimals. I want to validate this input as a number that is 5 or higher and less than 100. Using the `min` and `max` attributes I was able to create the following HTML snippet. It appears to function correctly in every browser but looks horrible.

```
<input type="number" step="any" min="5" max="99.9999999999999999" required>
```

[image: The validation]

Is there a decent way to do this (without rounding shenanigans)?

I know this can be easily solved using JavaScript but I'm wondering if there's a decent way to do this with just HTML. I'm trying to validate the input of users that have HTML5 form validation but not JavaScript. Checking this input server-side forces the user to load the page again, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The max attribute defines the top value and the defined value is included. To change this behaviour you should add a sort of added validation with javascript: either to check if the number is 100 or directly replacing the min max attribute with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994576/maximum-allowed-value-for-input-type-text).

Comment: @LelioFaieta I'm aware of JavaScript validation and am already using it to check the input again before submitting the form (in case the browser doesn't support some of the attributes) and once more server side. I'm just wondering if there's a decent way to do this with the `min`, `max` attributes since 99.999... returns a message that the number should be lower than 100 instead of 99.999.... This could just be rounding in the message though.

Comment: As I told you before: max value specified is always included in the range as per HTML spec. So you cannot do anything more about that with plain html

Comment: @LelioFaieta I know the max value is always included. In this case the browser reports the number 100 instead of 99.999... however. [Example.](http://i.imgur.com/ktyXQ0e.png) (Every browser I tested showed this same behavior.) That's why I was wondering if there is a decent way to (fake) exclude the maximum number cross browser or alternatively, if there exists an attribute for this purpose.

Comment: Have you tried reducing your coeffcient (decimal digits)? Keep it under 13 digits, and the browser will show you the correct validation message. The `max` attribute [is a floating-point number](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.max), and an [algorithm to convert a string to a number](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-min-and-max-attributes) is applied during the [value sanitization algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-input-element.html#value-sanitization-algorithm)..........

Comment: ......Looking at the Chromium source, it seems it returns the validation message via [`serializeForNumberType`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/html/parser/HTMLParserIdioms.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=87&rcl=1454545816) which in turn does a [`toString`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/Decimal.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=941&rcl=1454545816) to convert the decimal, which rounds it up beyond the `maxDigits` which is a const to `DBL_DIG`.

Comment: @Abhitalks The max attribute has this horrible value to allow the user to fill in any number of decimal digits. If I were to reduce it to "99.9999999999" (12 decimal digits) then "99.99999999999" (13 decimal digits) would fail the check. The current number of decimal digits causes any number of decimal digits to pass but anything equal to or higher than 100 fails. This is horrible and hacky but the validation works.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you want to include this css styles in the `<head>` from Google this makes Input Fields look better than standart Input Fields from your browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
```